# background video is not covering the full screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The video in the background is not covering the full screen,it's not autoplaying on my phone also.

```
enter code here

body video {
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width:auto;
    z-index: -1000;


    position: fixed;
    pointer-events: none;

    background-size:cover;
    autoplay:true;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;


}
```

Comment: Please read the FAQ [Something in my website or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/215552), where the answer is "No.". Pasting in a bit of CSS code with no HTML doesn't really count toward introducing a [mre] to the question. Please read [ask] for tips on how to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a fixed position, and a min-width of 100%. Look at the example below. PS - I used a div, because I don't know how to upload a video on SO, but it works on videos.

```css
#myVideo {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div id = "myVideo"></div>
```